# Write nullable integer values back to spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am using Excel as a reporting tool, for my desktop application. The app is written in C# (VS 2019).

The gist of my code is to obtain a range object from the worksheet, populate an array of null-able integers and write it back out to the same worksheet.

[image: Basic worksheet structure]

So far I have obtained a range of cells, where startRow is the first row highlighted in yellow:

```
Range startRow = (Range) input.Range["E" + row.ToString(), "K" + row.ToString()];
```

Initialise the local array as:

```
double?[,] startArray = new double?[1, 7];
```

Set the relevant values:

```
startArray[1,2] = 9.75;
```

And finally, write the data back:

```
  startRow.Value2 = startArray;
```

When I write the array back, I get the error

```
The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

In this case, I assume that it is because I have some null-able values in the array, as if I do not use a null-able array and as a result its values are zero by default, this works OK, but wites zeros out into the spreadsheet.

I did try using:

```
string[,] startArray = new string[1, 7];
```

which does work, but any fields that does have a value, are not seen as numeric and causes Excel formulae not to work.

So to my question, can I get the array to write back to Excel with nulls, or do I have to revert to using the cell object and only update the cells which contain a value?

Comment: Consider not using interop for this; straight file manipulation using something like [Jan Kallman's EPPlus](https://www.google.com/search?q=epplus) will work more reliably/quickly and wont require Excel to be installed on the target machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, just the fact of writing this post has enabled me to fix it.

The simple answer is to write directly to the range only the values which contain a value.

So something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (startArray[0, i] != null) startRow[1, i + 1] = startArray[0, i];
}
```

As for EPPlus, it looks a fantastic product, but as I already pay for an Excel license would find this a little over kill as a paid license would also be needed for EPPlus.